# How to add custom module with package in gradle?

Tags: java, automated-tests, build.gradle, customization, cucumber-jvm

I'm unable to add custom source set in my gradle project. How to initialize the version numbers in here?
My gradle file looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    demo
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set custom `sourceSets` like this in your build.gradle

```
  main {
    java {
      srcDirs = ['src/gen/java', 'src/main/java']
    }
  }
```

The `srcDirs` is an array, so you can specify more than one source directory.

You can also specify custom source directories for your tests

```
  test {
    java {
      srcDirs = ['src/integrated-test/java', 'src/test/java']
    }
  }
```

You can find some more info here https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-source-sets in section 3. They use the example for integrated tests, but the idea is the same.

Here is the official gradle document for source sets https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have found a solution and pasting in comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
If your requirement is projectFolder/src/ -> Here you want to create a custom module other than the main and test. follow the below one.
Its worked in Intellj ide.

```
sourceSets {
    customModuleName.java.srcDir "src/customModuleName"
    customModuleName.resources.srcDir "src/customModuleName"
}
```

// After adding the above block in build file. Go ahead and create a directory, it will show a module name in suggestion
// Then inside module, Go to create a package. Here we can find java and resources folder in suggestion